# Codeigniter - query does not execute from a specific controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I face this problem:

I have a function in a Model which runs a select query: I call it from the controller A (not real name). When I call the same method, but from the controller B, the PHP script stops when the query executes.

This function receives a number or an array as parameter. I've set the value of the parameter within the model to be sure I don't send wrong data from the controller B, and it keeps happening.

The query:

```
$arrConversas = $this->db->where_in('codigo_conversa', $codigo_conversa)
                     ->group_by(['codigo_origem','codigo_destino',
                                 'tipo_origem', 'tipo_destino'])
                     ->get('conversa_mensagem')->result();
```

I think the code isn't wrong because it runs normally from controller A.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

Thank you guys. The problem was a procedure that was running before this query, I tried to flush the connection and clean the cache and the problemas was there yet, then I use a `$this->db->reconnect();` .  Not the best solution but this action won't be used everyday.

I saw on the debugging the error: "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now".

Thanks again!

Comment: Are you loading the model in controller B?

Comment: Use `$this->db->last_query();` and see what is your last query had been execute

Comment: There could be two things causing problem,
1st you are not loading the model in the controller A.
2nd check if your controllers and models have this as a contructor `function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }` .

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Check the logs if not, without this it could be anything.

Comment: Hi, you might want to add an answer to this question yourself and accept it, so it's obvious that the problem has been resolved! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a procedure that was running before this query, then I used `$this->db->reconnect();` and it worked !

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not write the $this->load->database(); in your constructor in the model.